# Scanning business cards to CiviCRM

Tags: extension, import, mobile

Anyone working on creating an app to scan a business card and have that information transfer to CiviCRM? Or ideas for how to create this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall seeing any discussion on this since this [forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=15411.0) and i don't suspect anything has changed. Scanning cards would be a 3rd party process and that would then presumably provide a csv to import.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally I would find a very popular card scanner that has an API available with an event model with callbacks. Then I would create a desktop extension or app in a technology supported by the scanner that gets the scanned contact info from it, and have it use CiviCRM's REST API to insert the contact. The app will need to have a configuration file or interface to allow the CiviCRM REST url and login info at a minimum. I'd likely add an option to specify a tag or group for contacts inserted from the business card scanner. The app will need to check that the tag or group still exists everytime it is about to add it to a new contact.

Answer (score 3):

It’d have to be some type of automation first that does OCR, then feeds it into CiviCRM. Maybe in combination with the [Google Apps extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-apps-sync)?

Comment: Hi Peter, I'am interested on an OCR feeding the CRM. Is there anything reliable at the moment? Thank you!

Comment: OCR as a function is outside of th scope of CiviCRM. Getting an app that can make the data available via API could be used to access the data and store it within the database. This will need to be custom developed. I'm unaware of an existing implementation.